Manage ACL in azure to control access on specific container or directory level
What is the purpose of manage ACL in Azure?
Suppose we have storage account
storage-ACCOUNT --- LANDING
                 --- CONTAINER1 -- HR
                 --- CONTAINER2 -- SALES

only HR should be accessable to one person no SAS key Approach
only SALES should be accessable to other person no SAS key Approach
where there are coantiner inside the storage account which stores the data according to business wise.
How can we use ACL to give access to only one container? and how can we test this once ACL is granted
i have tried giving the ACL to file inside the container with out the IAM role but its is not working


Manage ACL in Azure to control access at specific container or directory levels.

According to this MS-Document,
Azure Data Lake Gen2 accounts can be managed by various models like RBAC, ABAC, SAS, Shared Key, and ACL.
In your scenario, I suggest you use ABAC (Attribute-based access control) to access particular containers, folders, and files.
In Azure AD, you can establish two security groups: one for SALES and one for HR. Following that, you can assign individuals to the HR security group who want access to the HR container and the SALES security group who want access to the SALES container.
Then you can follow this MS-Document and assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to your HR security group with conditions.
Portal:

Condition:

This will allow access to a specific container with specific permissions for particular groups with users.
Structure:

